# Autoscale documentation for Azure Logic Apps Standard

Tags: azure, documentation, azure-logic-apps, scalability, azure-logic-app-standard

I have been trying to find some authoritative documentation on scaling behaviour of Azure logic apps standard. There is a lot of documentation on event driven scaling of function apps elastic premium, but none that I can find on Logic apps standard?

Whilst under the covers they have a lot of similarities, I am wondering if there is Microsoft published documentation on Azure logic apps standard scalability/auto-scale.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Standard logic apps which were hosted on (WS1,WS2,WS3) plan support elastic scale out which is similar to elastic premium in functions and supports event driven scaling.

We don't have any separate documentation for autoscaling in standard logic and azure functions, you can refer to this documentation for [more information on autoscale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal#plan-and-sku-settings).

Comment: So event driven scaling feature of functions, does that apply to logic apps standard as well? for example when using service-bus trigger, is the event driven scaling behaviour same for both logic apps standard and function apps elastic premium?

Comment: @GopalKrishnan refer to my above updated answer.